# Do we need the [technology] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed we have a [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) tag. It's excerpt states this:

> Questions relating to the use of technology to further space exploration.

I'm wondering what the community's opinion is on this tag - it seems to me like it is almost intrinsic - there isn't much space exploration *not* having to do with technology.

Thoughts?

Comment: I see it has been nearly six years since we had this discussion and we never did anything about the tag. Do we still want it gone? There are now 90 questions on this tag, and some of them have it as the only tag, meaning there would need to be an effort to add more specific tags if we were going to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, let's first analyze what questions are currently tagged under [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology), there's not too many of them:

- [What happens to defunct lunar and Mars rovers? What technological barriers prevent humanity from creating a perpetual rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/948/what-happens-to-defunct-lunar-and-mars-rovers-what-technological-barriers-preve)
  [mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars) [the-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon) [rovers](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rovers) [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *rovers*
- [Has any CubeSat flown with an active propulsion system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/940/has-any-cubesat-flown-with-an-active-propulsion-system)
  [propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propulsion) [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [cubesat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubesat)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *cubesat*
- [Why did the ESA choose SPARC for LEON?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/729/why-did-the-esa-choose-sparc-for-leon)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [flight-computer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-computer)
  [esa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esa)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *flight-computer*
- [What technologies are being developed to ease the supply chain burden for space travel? [closed]](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/679/what-technologies-are-being-developed-to-ease-the-supply-chain-burden-for-space)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [supply](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supply) [robotics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *robotics*
- [Is it better to build a spaceship in total or in parts for orbital assembly? [duplicate]](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/447/is-it-better-to-build-a-spaceship-in-total-or-in-parts-for-orbital-assembly)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [orbital-assembly](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-assembly)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *orbital-assembly*
- [How do spacecraft measure onboard gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/359/how-do-spacecraft-measure-onboard-gravity)
  [gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity) [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [physics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) [instrument](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *instrument*
- [Is there any research going on launching into orbit with “space guns”? Why (not)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51/is-there-any-research-going-on-launching-into-orbit-with-space-guns-why-not)
  [launch](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launch) [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)
  <sub>[image: huh]</sub> *technology* tag is **arguably necessary**, possibly previously implied by **launch**
- [What technological barriers, if any, prevent a manned mission to Mars at this time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-technological-barriers-if-any-prevent-a-manned-mission-to-mars-at-this-ti)
  [mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars) [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)
  <sub>[image: ok]</sub> *technology* tag is **necessary**, but could possibly be implied by adding other, more specific tags
- [Can spacecraft be made invisible to stations on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/can-spacecraft-be-made-invisible-to-stations-on-earth)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [artificial-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellites) [tracking](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) [stealth](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *artificial-satellites*, *tracking*
- [Do any systems in space use Artificial Intelligence yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/do-any-systems-in-space-use-artificial-intelligence-yet)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [flight-computer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-computer) [unmanned](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *flight-computer*, *unmanned*
- [Has any technology been demonstrated that allows a useful payload to survive at least one month on Venus' surface?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/has-any-technology-been-demonstrated-that-allows-a-useful-payload-to-survive-at)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [venus](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venus) [cooling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling)
  <sub>[image: ok]</sub> *technology* tag is **necessary**, but could be implied by replacing *cooling* by *artificial-cooling*
- [What happens to defunct lunar and Mars rovers? What technological barriers prevent humanity from creating a perpetual rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/948/what-happens-to-defunct-lunar-and-mars-rovers-what-technological-barriers-preve)
  [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars) [the-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon) [rovers](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rovers)
  <sub>[image: del]</sub> *technology* tag is **unnecessary**, already implied by *rovers*

So this is what question tagged [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) we currently have. Out of 11 questions in total, 8 have the keyword "technology" already implied with other tags they use, one is borderline, and two possibly necessary, but "technology" could be implied by adding other existing or new, and more specific tags.

These statistics seem to concur with the assessment that the keyword "technology" is already intrinsic to the nature of Space Exploration website, which, by definition is **Q&A site for spacecraft operators, scientists, engineers, and enthusiasts**. Use of "enthusiasts" is only ambiguous on its own, but not in the context of this definition. Other keywords in the definition - "spacecraft operators", "scientists", "engineers" - go hand in hand with the keyword "technology".

I wasn't entirely sure, before I started analyzing our current contents, but now support the notion to abolish the tag [technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and rather add tags to those three questions that are arguably borderline ambiguously tagged, to make them implicitly imply the keyword "technology".

Comment: Would go even further: blacklist the tag.

Comment: @Deer Absolutely - it's one of those tags that will always try to come back.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a legitimate tag, if applied to a question that has a strong focus on a particular technology, rather than application.

For example, if someone asked about what tensile strength would be required to be able to build a space elevator, and how the current strongest mass-produced material compares with that requirement. Such a question seems to me would fit such a tag.

I agree, though, that such a tag could be prone to overuse or misunderstanding, as some of the high level tags on Science Fiction and Movies & TV often are.

Comment: I agree that the tag does have some valid uses. Looking through the last year or two several tagged questions really do seem to be about "technology" as a thing in and of itself.

Answer (score -4):

I'll play the devil's advocate on this one, and give it a spin.

*tongue-in-cheek* What about parapsychology/ESP/psi?

From http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/vision_remota/esp_visionremota_9a.htm

> The so-called Father of Soviet Rocketry, K.E. Tsiolkovsky, stated that:
>
> “In the coming era of space flights, telepathic abilities are
>   necessary. While the space rocket must bring men toward knowledge of
>   the grand secrets in the universe, the study of psychic phenomena can
>   lead us toward knowledge of the mysteries of the human mind. It is
>   precisely the solution of this secret which promises the greatest
>   achievements.”
>
> There are reports that the Soviets are training their cosmonauts in
>   telepathy to back up their electronic equipment while in outer space.
>   One of these back-up schemes is known to involve coded telepathic
>   messages. This method was previously demonstrated in March 1967, when
>   a coded telepathic message was flashed from Moscow to Leningrad. The
>   involvement of astronauts or cosmonauts in telepathy experiments is
>   not necessarily unprecedented. In February 1971, during the Apollo 14
>   flight to the moon, astronaut Edgar Mitchell made 150 separate
>   attempts to project his thoughts from inside the space capsule back to
>   an individual on earth.
>
> [Appendix 1, pages 25-26.]